# Add a header to an outgoing request by a filter in WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm using Java Spring WebFlux for client and server, and I want to customize my request from client to server by adding a custom header to it. I'm already using WebFilter for another purpose, but it seems like it's only working for incoming requests and responses (such as a request from FE and a response to it).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are multiple ways of specifying custom headers.

If the headers are static, you can specify them during `WebClient` instance creation using `defaultHeader` or `defaultHeaders` methods:

```
WebClient.builder().defaultHeader("headerName", "headerValue")
WebClient.builder().defaultHeaders(headers -> headers.add("h1", "hv1").add("h2", "hv2"))
```

If the headers are dynamic but the header value generation is common for all requests, you can use `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor` configured during `WebClient` instance creation:

```
WebClient
    .builder()
    .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(
        request -> Mono.just(ClientRequest.from(request)
                                          .header("X-HEADER-NAME", "value")
                                          .build())
    )
    .build();
```

If headers are dynamic and specific per each use of `WebClient`, you can configure headers per call:

```
webClient.get()
    .header("headerName", getHeaderValue(params))
    .retrieve();
```

Comment: `request -> request.headers().add("headerName", getHeaderValuePer(request)))` gives me an `UnsupportedOperationException` because the returned list of headers is of type `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders`, which describes the problem in its name.

Comment: I updated the answer. `ClientRequest` is immutable, so you have to build a new instance of it to modify the headers.

Comment: any way to **remove** or **replace** header, instead of **adding** new ones?